# WSO2: Developer Studio 3.2.0/ESB project: unable to add arguments to an EJB mediator

Tags: parameters, ejb, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

When using Developer Studio (ESB project), I'm unable to add arguments to an EJB mediator
- neither via the GUI (the corresponding property doesn't exist)
- nor via XML 
For example

```
<ejb beanstalk="xx" class="xxx" method="yyy" target="zzz" ...>
 <args>
  <arg .... />
 </args>
</ejb>
```

gives once saved

```
<ejb beanstalk="xx" class="xxx" method="yyy" target="zzz" .../>
```

When I use the ESB console, I can add these arguments without any problem.
I guess it's a bug but I don't have any account in order to create a JIRA.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the case it is definitely a Bug in the Dev Studio 3.2.0 ESB editor. However we have fix this problem in Dev Studio 3.3.0 version and I am able to create EJB mediator with Arguments.

Please try out this scenario with Dev Studio 3.3.0 Alpha 1 release which is available at [here](http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/3.3.0/Alpha/)

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana